# Spock specify data table for multiple result values?

Tags: spock

I have a set of inputs (a,b,c) and an output type for each set of them. The output type has two fields (p,q). Can I specify values for output type fields like this as part of where data table?

```
def "test service"(int a, int b, int c) {

    setup:
         req = reqBldr(a,b,c)
         expectedRsp = rspBldr(p,q)

    when:
         rsp = service.call(req)

    then:
         expectedRsp=rsp

    where:
    a | b | c || p | q
    1 | 3 | 3 || 0 | 0
    7 | 4 | 4 || 0 | 1
    0 | 0 | 0 || 1 | 1

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. As the error message will tell you, the method either needs to declare five or zero parameters (all data variables or none). Another error message will tell you that you need to use `==` rather than `=` in the assertion. Last but not least, Groovy requires local variables to be declared with `def`. Otherwise you should get a `MissingPropertyException`.